# looking for a matrix inverse in keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I want to implement a custom layer in keras. Unfortunately one part of the calculation requires the pseudo inverse (to solve x = (A'A)⁻¹A'b). Now I am missing the functionality of `K.inverse`. Is there a way I can solve an OLS equation using the keras backend?

```
def call(inputs, **kwargs):
    A = ...
    b = ...
    return K.inverse(K.transpose(A) @ A) @ K.transpose(A) @ b
```

Maybe I can read it back to numpy arrays do the inverse and then feed it back to a tensor or similar?

Comment: you can use tensorflow's inverse(tf.linalg.inv) inside a keras Lambda layer, that way, you don't have to create a custom layer, just a custom function.

Comment: good enough thanks. you might add this as an answer. it just does not work for other Keras backed, which is fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use tensorflow's inverse(tf.linalg.inv) inside a keras Lambda layer, that way, you don't have to create a custom layer, just a custom function.